# Store Byte[] in Access 2007, which datatype is used

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, arrays

I want to store a byte[] in an MS Access 2007 database, which datatype should I use?

I have checked it using Memo but it's not properly saving.

I am doing it like this:

```
        OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\Open Source\\Desktop\\UMS\\UMSS.Accdb");        
        OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TEACHER(NAME,DEP,TCHTYPE,NIC,CELLNO,FINGER)VALUES(@NAME,@DEP,@TTYPE,@NICE,@CELL,@FINGER)";
        insertCommand.Connection = objConnection;
        // insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", name);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP", dep);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TTYPE", ttype);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NICE", nic);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CELL", cell);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FINGER", finger);

        objConnection.Open();
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objConnection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Data Is Entered");// C# Document
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Memo is for long-form text. You need a *binary* type - [Microsoft Access Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @crashmstr then sugest me which datatype will best fit.

Comment: I gave you a link and a suggestion for using a binary type. Can you not find a binary type in the documentation on that page?